# What is the standard for communicating in JSON when you're putting it out and not bringing it in?

Tags: json, flutter

I am told I need to communicate in flutter over the web using JSON. I know how to bring in JSON data and convert it into a Dart object. How am I expected to put *out* the JSON? Should I output the JSON in the form of a Dart object? How does that work? I've tried to do research but can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a method to your class that serialized it into a dictionary like this:

```
class Car {
  final int nWheels;
  final String color;
  
  Car(this.nWheels, this.color);
  
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "nWheels": this.nWheels,
    "color": this.color,
  }
}
```

The resulting map can then be converted to a JSON string by using the [flutter json library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html). That would look like this:

```
Car car = Car(4, "blue-ish");
String json = jsonEncode(car.toMap());
```

`json` is now a JSON-encoded String that can be transmitted to the server.